# Any ideas how to replace bulb in this bathroom ceiling fan?

Tags: exhaust-fan, replacement, bulb, bathroom-fixtures

This is an old bathroom ceiling fan & light fixture. The bulb has gone out, now I cannot find away to open it and replace the bulb.

There are no screws that I can see. I played around with glass and managed to pooped it up but now its just sitting in the frame stuck but I can rotate it. But again its not sitting on any grove, its loose now.

How can I open this fixture to replace the bulb? Thanks

[image]

Comment: I am going to guess that the little tabs/notches around the perimeter of the glass can be somehow depressed (whilst supporting the glass) to release the glass cover for bulb access.

Comment: Also, that white ring should be spring loaded and should just pull down maybe revealing some screws

Comment: i am with jack on this one but i may be a twist and lock system. Turn the white ring counter clockwise and see if it unlocks.

Answer (score 4):

That white ring should be spring loaded and should just pull down maybe revealing some screws.

Answer (score 3):

I acted on clue that it should be spring loaded from homedepot guys. I didn't know what that really means but I tried to see if I can pull down the assembly and it does pull down!

There are two anchor points which sort of spring loaded. I was able to pull one side down only which allowed access to the bulb and I replaced it. I don't think it's necessary to pull down from both sides but I guess that could be done too.

After replacing the bulb, I just pushed it up and all done so it was kind of easy.

You do have to put a little bit of force to pull it down, I was scared if it will break or something but no.

Given this information, you can examine the fixture again and can probably spot the two anchor points inside the fixture (or note that fixture is tied at two points when you pull down) so you know that's the mechanism you have.

Answer (score 0):

Just opened mine.  There were two screws across from each other, you have to use a skinny flat head screwdriver to loosen the screws only a little then turn entire fixture clockwise, and the whole light fixture will come off giving you access to light bulb and for cleaning dust.

Comment: Glad you got yours opened, but it seems yours has a different mechanism than the original akser's does, since he posted that his was a pull straight down. Never hurts to have an another known good option, though, as there are many different assemblies.